# How can I debug a file containing tests from Google Test built with CMake on MacOS M1

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am trying to debug my test file using Google Test, but it isn't working. My file structure is as follows:

```
- data-structures
    - linked-lists
        - tests-linked-list.cpp
        - linked-list.hpp
        - linked-list-abstract.hpp
- googletest
- CMakeLists.txt
```

My CMakeLists file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(data-structures)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/e2239ee6043f73722e7aa812a459f54a28552929.zip
)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(googletest)

include_directories(googletest/include)

add_executable(
  tests-linked-list
    linked-lists/tests-linked-list.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
  tests-linked-list
  PRIVATE gtest
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(tests-linked-list)
```

And I'm building googletest and testing the code with these commands:

```
cmake -S . -B build
cmake --build build
cd build && ctest
```

And this works perfectly. But I want to debug the file. I want to go into my header files and see what is happening between the assertions, but the debugger won't run. When I press F5 (on VSCode) and use the default C++ debugger task, it gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++14 -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/enrico/Developer/data-structures/linked-lists/tests-linked-list.cpp -o /Users/enrico/Developer/data-structures/linked-lists/tests-linked-list
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)", referenced from:
      _main in tests-linked-list-b41237.o
  "testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()", referenced from:
      RUN_ALL_TESTS() in tests-linked-list-b41237.o
  "testing::UnitTest::Run()", referenced from:
      RUN_ALL_TESTS() in tests-linked-list-b41237.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I doing something wrong? If I need to provide more information, let me know.

Comment: i think you build the program with the release build type. And in that type no debug informations are generated so the debugger does not know how to match your code to the executable. You could try to add `-DBUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo` to your cmake call

Comment: You seem to be asking about one thing (how to debug a unit-test on a specific system) but then you get some linker errors that you also seem to ask about? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're actually asking about. The title is totally unrelated to the errors you get.

Comment: And the problem seems to be that you're not invoking the CMake-generated build environment from yout VSCode `tasks.json` file, which means it won't link with the Google Test library (as can be seen in the command-line shown).

Comment: are you using the cmake plugin? Looks like you're trying to just build and run a single c++ file (which wont work), you'll need to either make your own launch task or use the cmake plugin to launch the executable

Comment: Please spend some time reading [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) on how to set up Visual Studio Code with Clang on macOS.